# RTL title in Actionbar in Appcompat-v7

Tags: android

I have an Actionbar with Appcompat-v7 in my project, I want to display the title in the right of it, I set `layoutDirection` Attribute to `rtl`, it works on API level greater than 17, but below it, it doesn't work, how can I correct it on API level less than 17?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Activity onCreate method to override default Appcompat-v7 action bar and you can setGravity to your actionBar title using this,

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBarTitleGravity();

    }
    private void ActionBarTitleGravity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

        textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        textview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

        textview.setText("ACTIONBAR");

        textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        textview.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        textview.setTextSize(20);

        actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        actionbar.setCustomView(textview);

    }
```